# How workflows.duration.ns.p99 is calculated in SignalFX

Tags: splunk, signalfx, p99

We are building load tests for a kafka based system. We created a workflow and we can see the metrics like workflows.duration.ns.p99 but we do not know how they are calculated.

Is workflows.duration.ns.p99 just a sum of p99 of services that are parts of workflow or is there some more sophisticated logic behind the scenes? Can we exclude particular services from those calculations? And more generally is it the right metric to show p99 for system that looks like this:

Producer -> Kafka Topic -> Consumer -> Database

(we want to measure how much time elapsed between calling producer and storing data in DB).